# login.microsoftonline.com refused to connect with SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-framework, azure-ad

Facing issue: 'login.microsoftonline.com refused to connect'. It faced while deploy .sppkg file to Site. Solution works fine with workbench, but not works when deploy.

Please suggest solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to set `isDomainIsolated = false` in your package-solution.json file. This may solve the issue of login.microsoftonline.com refusing to connect.